# WPF - Uncheck every other boxes when a box is checked

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

as the title suggests, I'm trying to find a way to do the following:
-I have multiple checkboxes in a xaml file (let's say 5). When any of these boxes is checked, I want every other box to automatically be unchecked.

While this isn't too hard in itself, I was wondering if there was a way to avoid the tedious process of creating 5 unique commands along with 5 unique booleans to be bound to my checkboxes.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With command...do you mean the event, that is triggered when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: If that is the case, you can create only one event, map all checkboxes to the same event, check which checkbox fired the event using the arguments (sender, e) and finally loop through the remaining ones. However, I am not sure if that is actually easier in any way...

Comment: There's a built in solution to your problem. The [RadioButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.radiobutton) uses groups in which only one box can be selected.

Comment: @Funk RadioButton can not be unchecked by default

Comment: @Muhammad That's true, but the use case for that is rare. Once a box is checked, you typically enter the "multiple choice" scenario, where one box must be checked in order to continue. You may want none of the boxes are checked when the view is loaded, just not to provide a default. In which case some validation usually alarms the user if he forgets to check any of the boxes.

Comment: Indeed, the radio button does exactly what I need to do, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really seems to me that what you actually want is a RadioButton, which natively does it.

But just in case you really want a checkbox, you can do it like this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="container">
    <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var checkbox in container.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
        checkbox.IsChecked = sender.Equals(checkbox);
}
```

Comment: It is indeed exactly what I was looking for! The previous software used checkboxes for the same functionnality so I immediatly went towards checkboxes, but this does exactly what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have something like this in `.xaml`

```
<CheckBox Content="CB1" IsChecked="{Binding IsCb1Checked}" />
<!-- Some other controls and panels -->
<CheckBox Content="CB2" IsChecked="{Binding IsCb2Checked}" />
<!-- Some other controls and panels -->
<CheckBox Content="CB3" IsChecked="{Binding IsCb3Checked}" />
```

You can do a small trick in the setters of the boolean properties, keep in mind that you won't update the status of the other checkboxes if the user uncheck the checked CheckBox

```
private bool _isCb1Checked;

public bool IsCb1Checked
{
    set
    {
        if (_isCb1Checked == value) return;
        _isCb1Checked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (value)
            UpdateCheckBoxStatus(nameof(IsCb1Checked));
    }
    get => _isCb1Checked;
}

private bool _isCb2Checked;

public bool IsCb2Checked
{
    set
    {
        if (_isCb2Checked == value) return;
        _isCb2Checked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (value)
            UpdateCheckBoxStatus(nameof(IsCb2Checked));
    }
    get => _isCb2Checked;
}

private bool _isCb3Checked;

public bool IsCb3Checked
{
    set
    {
        if (_isCb3Checked == value) return;
        _isCb3Checked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (value)
            UpdateCheckBoxStatus(nameof(IsCb3Checked));
    }
    get => _isCb3Checked;
}

private void UpdateCheckBoxStatus(string propertyName)
{
    IsCb1Checked = propertyName == nameof(IsCb1Checked);
    IsCb2Checked = propertyName == nameof(IsCb2Checked);
    IsCb3Checked = propertyName == nameof(IsCb3Checked);
}
```

In action..

[image]

Comment: This is very similar to what I was already doing, and it indeed works great, but I decided to go towards radio buttons!

Comment: Sure, but since the question is about "how to uncheck checkboxes when on is checked", I think you should accept an answer that implements this behavior